# TreeView ignore double click only at checkbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

I have a treeview with checkbox, I'm trying to disable the double click only when this is done in the checkbox.

I found a way to totally disable the double click but it was not what I wanted.

I appreciate if you can help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want to know a DoubleClick event occurred from the CheckBox:

```
private void TreeViewDoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var localPosition = treeView.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
    var hitTestInfo = treeView.HitTest(localPosition);
    if (hitTestInfo.Location == TreeViewHitTestLocations.StateImage) 
        return;

    // ... Do whatever other processing you want
}
```

Comment: I knew there had to be a better way than what I answered with, but couldn't figure it out. +1

Comment: I'm not sure this works. The bug seems to actually clog all double click events. If you double click a checkbox, no double click events fire at all. If you then single click pretty much anywhere, *then* the double click events fire, but because they've fired so late, they end up with wrong information in their eventargs.

Answer (score 16):

I found this question when googling for the same bug. The problem with NoodleFolk's solution is that it disables expanding the three by double clicking on an item. By combining NoodleFolk's answer with john arlens answer, you would get something like this:

```
class NewTreeView : TreeView
{
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0x203) // identified double click
        {
            var localPos = PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
            var hitTestInfo = HitTest(localPos);
            if (hitTestInfo.Location == TreeViewHitTestLocations.StateImage)
                m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
            else
                base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
        else base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

I (quickly) tested this solution, and it seems to work.

Comment: This answer seems nice but it would be better with the following change, as appears in @MichaelRupp's answer:  

`if (m.Msg == 0x0203 && this.CheckBoxes)`

Comment: @FaultyOverflow this.CheckBoxes will indicate if the ThreeView has checkboxes or not. It does not indicate if the click came from within the checkbox.  So if your class can be used both with or without checkboxes, the check may be useful. In my case, I only used the derived class NewTreeView in a case where i already knew that I used check boxes.

Comment: You are not wrong, but as stated in the OP's question, "I'm trying to disable the double click only when this is done in the checkbox", so...

Comment: yeah but this.CheckBoxes does not tell you if the click came from within the checkbox. It tells you if the treeview has checkboxes or not. The if (hitTestInfo.Location == TreeViewHitTestLocations.StateImage) tells you if the click was witin the checkbox or not.

Answer (score 14):

**Option 1**: Completely disable the double click event.
Create a customer control

```
class MyTreeView : TreeView
{
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0x0203)
        {
            m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
        }
        else
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
}
```

and in your designer file ( form.Designer.cs ), look for where the control was created, and replace the call to TreeView constructor with your new control.

```
this.treeView1 = new MyTreeView();
```

**Option 2**: Treat a double click event as two single click events

```
class MyTreeView : TreeView
{
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0x0203)
        {
            m.Msg = 0x0201;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

Personally I think option 2 is more intuitive. When user clicks the check box twice, the checkbox is not checked.

Answer (score 5):

Combining the above answers, I found this to be the best solution for me. Double clicking on a node to expand its children still works, only double clicking on a checkbox is affected and fixed:

```
class MyTreeView : TreeView
{
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
      if (m.Msg == 0x0203 && this.CheckBoxes)
      {
        var localPos = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
        var hitTestInfo = this.HitTest(localPos);
        if (hitTestInfo.Location == TreeViewHitTestLocations.StateImage)
        {
          m.Msg = 0x0201;
        }
      }
      base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```