# CheckBox not work properly when clicked on quickly multiple times

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, treeview

What this code do:

1. If parent node is checked/unchecked, also check/uncheck all child nodes.
2. If just one child node is checked, also check parent node.

   ```
   Private Sub TreeView1_AfterCheck(sender As Object, e As TreeViewEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.AfterCheck
       If updatingTreeView Then Return
       updatingTreeView = True
       CheckNode(e.Node, e.Node.Checked)
       HasCheckedChildNode = 0
       updatingTreeView = False
   End Sub
   ```

   Private Sub CheckNode(node As TreeNode, isChecked As Boolean)
       If node.Parent IsNot Nothing Then
           HasCheckedNode(node.Parent)
           If Not isChecked And HasCheckedChildNode > 0 Then Return
           node.Parent.Checked = isChecked
       ElseIf node.Parent Is Nothing Then
           For Each cn As TreeNode In node.Nodes
               cn.Checked = isChecked
           Next
       End If
   End Sub

   Private Sub HasCheckedNode(node As TreeNode)
       For Each cn As TreeNode In node.Nodes
           If cn.Checked = True Then
               HasCheckedChildNode += 1
           ElseIf cn.Checked = False Then
               HasCheckedChildNode -= 0
           End If
       Next
   End Sub

This code works fine.

**Problem:**

When I clicks quickly some of the checkboxes are checked and some no
E.g. Sometimes I checked the parent node but all child nodes still remain unchecked. Sometimes the parent node is unchecked but its child nodes still checked.

Please check the example image:

[image: this]

How to solve this, is this a problem with my PC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because the TreeView by default doesn't toggle the `Check` property of the TreeNode objects on mouse double click over the check box area. You need to intercept the `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK` messages, get `TreeViewHitTestInfo` of the double clicked point, and toggle the `Check` property if the double clicked point is over the check box.

Here's a custom TreeView for that, also it solves the main issue, checking/unchecking the parent and child nodes of the branch, just enable the `AutoCheckParents` and/or `AutoCheckChildren` properties for that.

```vb
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Windows.Forms

<DesignerCategory("Code")>
Public Class DoubleClickCheckTreeView
    Inherits TreeView

#Region "Properties"

    <Category("Behavior"),
        DefaultValue(False)>
    Public Property AutoCheckParents As Boolean = False

    <Category("Behavior"),
        DefaultValue(False)>
    Public Property AutoCheckChildren As Boolean = False

#End Region

#Region "Overrides"

    'Enable DoubleBuffered to reduce the flickering.
    Protected Overrides Sub OnHandleCreated(e As EventArgs)
        SendMessage(Handle,
                    TVM_SETEXTENDEDSTYLE,
                    IntPtr.op_Explicit(TVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER),
                    IntPtr.op_Explicit(TVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER))
        MyBase.OnHandleCreated(e)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
        If m.Msg = WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK AndAlso CheckBoxes Then
            Dim x As Integer = m.LParam.ToInt32() And &HFFFF
            Dim y As Integer = (m.LParam.ToInt32 >> 16) And &HFFFF
            Dim ht As TreeViewHitTestInfo = HitTest(x, y)

            If ht.Node IsNot Nothing AndAlso
                ht.Location = TreeViewHitTestLocations.StateImage Then
                OnBeforeCheck(New TreeViewCancelEventArgs(ht.Node,
                                                          False,
                                                          TreeViewAction.ByMouse))
                ht.Node.Checked = Not ht.Node.Checked
                OnAfterCheck(New TreeViewEventArgs(ht.Node, TreeViewAction.ByMouse))
                m.Result = IntPtr.Zero
                Return
            End If
        End If
        MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnAfterCheck(e As TreeViewEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnAfterCheck(e)

        If e.Action = TreeViewAction.Unknown OrElse
            Not CheckBoxes Then Return

        If AutoCheckParents Then
            Dim p = e.Node.Parent

            While p IsNot Nothing
                p.Checked = p.Nodes.Cast(Of TreeNode).Any(Function(x) x.Checked)
                p = p.Parent
            End While
        End If

        If AutoCheckChildren Then
            For Each tn As TreeNode In GetNodes(e.Node)
                tn.Checked = e.Node.Checked
            Next
        End If
    End Sub

#End Region

#Region "Private Methods"

    Private Iterator Function GetNodes(node As TreeNode) As IEnumerable(Of TreeNode)
        For Each n As TreeNode In node.Nodes
            Yield n
            For Each c As TreeNode In GetNodes(n)
                Yield c
            Next
        Next
    End Function

#End Region

#Region "API"

    Private Const TVM_SETEXTENDEDSTYLE As Integer = &H1100 + 44
    Private Const TVM_GETEXTENDEDSTYLE As Integer = &H1100 + 45
    Private Const TVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER As Integer = &H4
    Private Const WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK As Integer = &H203

    <DllImport("user32.dll")>
    Private Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr,
                                       ByVal msg As Integer,
                                       ByVal wp As IntPtr,
                                       ByVal lp As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    End Function

#End Region

End Class
```

- Add a new class to your project and paste this code.
- Rebuild.
- Drop an instance of the DoubleClickCheckTreeView or change the type of the existing default TreeView in the Designer.

[image: SOQ61299089]

---

> **Related**

---

◉ [AfterCheck and AfterSelect events in TreeView, Windows Forms (c#)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58547452/10216583)

---

Comment: Big Thanks to you sir, @JQSOFT. Your code worked like a charm!. Although I do not fully understand your code, I want to know more. Could you please recommend me  where should I read.

Comment: @SRN Welcome buddy. Just ask yourself a simple question. **How does it work?**, search for answers, read books, code, do mistakes, learn from them. Good luck.

Comment: @SRN Thank you. Just added a new property to separate toggling the parent and child nodes since there is application for each.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine you would have to handle your double click event when its fired, and I suspect your code for that is going to look very similar to your single click event (but who knows)