# Beginner: TreeView with checkboxes and recursion in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, recursion, treeview, child-nodes

first post and a new coder so bare with me if you need more info than I am giving. I am trying to create a treeview with checkboxes in a hierarchy (see pic). My issue is i want to create some sort of recursion which deselects and selects child nodes when parent nodes are checked or vice versa.

I am using VS with winforms and been googling for 2 days on how to do this, unfortunately the examples online are either too advanced for me or dont work. I found a [Tutorial](https://www.thebestcsharpprogrammerintheworld.com/2020/05/26/treeview-with-checkbox-in-wpf/) on how to do this exactly with indeterminate checkboxes as well which would be a big bonus but it is for WPF.

I managed to create buttons which are able to (un)check all buttons with some examples online. Please can someone guide, a beginner who is finding programming AMAZING so far, in the right direction :)

```
 private void button_checkAllNodes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkAllNodes(treeView1.Nodes);
    }

    private void button_uncheckAllNodes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UncheckAllNodes(treeView1.Nodes);
    }

    public void checkAllNodes(TreeNodeCollection nodes)
     {
         foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
         {
             node.Checked = true;
             checkChildren(node, true);
         }
     }
    public void UncheckAllNodes(TreeNodeCollection nodes)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
        {
            node.Checked = false;
            checkChildren(node, false);
        }
    }

    private void checkChildren(TreeNode rootNode, bool isChecked)
     {
         foreach (TreeNode node in rootNode.Nodes)
         {
             checkChildren(node, isChecked);
             node.Checked = isChecked;
         }
     }

    private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        
    }
```

[Picture Treeview with (un)check All buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fzdS.png)

Comment: Not sure what your issue is.  The only thing I see wrong is when rootNode.Nodes is null.  So you need an IF statement to return from CheckAllNodes/UnCheckAllNodes when rootNode.Nodes is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's create a couple of extension methods for the `TreeNode` type, one that gets all the children of a node, and another that gets it's parents.

```cs
// Within your project's namespace...
static class TreeViewExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TreeNode> Children(this TreeNode node)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode n in node.Nodes)
        {
            yield return n;

            foreach (TreeNode child in Children(n))
                yield return child;
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TreeNode> Parents(this TreeNode node)
    {
        var p = node.Parent;

        while (p != null)
        {
            yield return p;

            p = p.Parent;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, all what you need to do is to handle the `TreeView.AfterCheck` event to toggle the `Checked` property of the nodes that the extension methods yield.

```cs
// +
using System.Linq;

private void treeView1_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Action == TreeViewAction.Unknown) return;

    foreach (TreeNode n in e.Node.Children())
        n.Checked = e.Node.Checked;

    // Comment this if you don't need it.
    foreach (TreeNode p in e.Node.Parents())
        p.Checked = p.Nodes.OfType<TreeNode>().Any(n => n.Checked);
}
```

Soon, you'll notice sometimes this solution won't work as it should when you click rapidly over the check boxes since they don't receive the mouse double click messages by default. Then, follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58547452/14171304) post or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61307707/14171304) to solve this problem. For now click slowly.

If you prefer though to use buttons to toggle the check state, then delete the `AfterCheck` handler and do instead:

```cs
private void btnCheckAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ToggleCheck(treeView1.SelectedNode, true);
}

private void btnUncheckAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ToggleCheck(treeView1.SelectedNode, false);
}

private void ToggleCheck(TreeNode node, bool state)
{
    node.Checked = state;

    foreach (TreeNode n in node.Children())
        n.Checked = state;

    // Optional...
    foreach (TreeNode n in node.Parents())
        n.Checked = state;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for this. Almost does exactly what I want. Apologies for the late reply as I have been away on holiday. How would I go about making it check/uncheck on the fly? Rather than having a button doing that on the selected nodes?

Comment: @Breakwin Welcome back. If you check the first version of my answer, you'll see that part. I thought you don't need it thus I remove it. I'll add it again.

Comment: brilliant, this did it. thank you very much. I just had to add the aftercheck event additionally. Apparently this did not get added to treeview when i created it.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treeview.aftercheck?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @jdweng , you are using recursion in checkChildren(). The base case is missing.
In recursion  checkChildren , add base case before
`foreach (TreeNode node in rootNode.Nodes)`
`if node is Null : rootNode=isChecked`