# TreeView checking/unchecking descendants - sometimes only root is affected

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

Consider a `TreeView` structure such as the following:

[image]

The goal is to have a node's descendants check or uncheck themselves accordingly when a particular node is checked. For example, in the above, if "D" is unchecked, "D A", "D A A" and "D A B" should uncheck themselves.

Currently, the code being used is as follows:

```
private void treeView_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Action != TreeViewAction.Unknown)
    {
        if (e.Node.Checked)
        {
            checkChildNodes(e.Node.Nodes);
        }
        else
        {
            uncheckChildNodes(e.Node.Nodes);
        }
    }
 }

private void checkChildNodes(TreeNodeCollection nodes)
{
    foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
    {
        node.Checked = true;

        if (node.Nodes.Count>0)
            checkChildNodes(node.Nodes);
    }
}

private void uncheckChildNodes(TreeNodeCollection nodes)
{
    foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
    {
        node.Checked = false;

        if (node.Nodes.Count>0)
            uncheckChildNodes(node.Nodes);
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that sometimes the checking/unchecking of descendants does not occur, when the "root" node is clicked very fast. How can this be solved?

What has also been tried, is using the `BeforeCheck` event, as per the following link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treeview.aftercheck?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Could it be that `treeView_AfterCheck` is called when `node.Checked = ...;` is changed inside your `uncheckChildNodes` method? If so, then add a `bool isAdjusting = false;` variable. In the `treeView_AfterCheck` method put `if (isAdjusting) return; isAdjusting = true;` and then set `isAdjusting = false;` at the end.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58547452/14171304